# Managing a massive design project

Tags: project-management, workflow

How do you manage a massive (60+ pages) design (HTML/CSS) Project? Like what is your workflow? How do you set milestones?

Comment: Why community wiki. This could be answered ! ( see s.Lott responde )

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529385/how-to-write-technical-specs-for-a-project-closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating a work breakdown structure (WBS) to make sure you capture all of the tasks/deliverables required for your project..here's some basic tasks:
 - develop a site map
 - develop wireframes and mockups - and get client approval
 - develop the main page and unique sub pages (assuming most sub pages are similiar in design and functionality, but different in content)
 - inventory content needs
 - build out primary page and 2-3 sub pages for final review/approval
 - complete implementation of site but add content to the sub-pages

Answer (score 3):

Step 1.  Simplify.  Find a way to simplify what they're asking for.  Often, this won't be apparent until you decompose and prioritize.

Step 2.  Decompose.  Inside every large project is a series of smaller projects waiting to get out.  Break the big job into "sprints" that will build something you can release in a reasonable amount of time.  2-3 weeks per sprint (or less) is a good target.

Step 3.  Prioritize.  They want something first.  Find out what that thing is and build that.

Step 4.  Review and see if you can simplify further.  Once you've decomposed and prioritized, you may see further opportunities to remove duplication, useless non-features, junk, fluff, bad ideas, and the like.

Comment: Not too helpful and to the point, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Nimbuz: If so, update your question to explain what *would* be helpful and to the point.